# How can you display two event items in an alert for react-big-calander onSelectEvent

Tags: reactjs, events, alert, react-big-calendar, onselect

[react-big-calander](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-big-calendar) - NPM Package

https://github.com/intljusticemission/react-big-calendar/blob/master/examples/demos/selectable.js

```
onSelectEvent={event => alert(event.distance, 'info')}
```

in this example, I want to display event.distance as well as event.title in the alert, but alert only accepts one value. How would I be able to display both within same alert?

I've tried to create a new function that runs when the event is triggered though it did not work so I thought about using a modal instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried a template literal:

```
onSelectEvent={event => alert(`${event.distance} ${event.title}`)}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That's exactly what I needed to do!